# How to deal with "remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser"?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I am working on a Django app using PostgreSQL as the back-end database. As per my understanding so far, if we do many concurrent calls of `save()` method, it raises the error `remaining connection slots are reserved for...`. To avoid this, in my `views.py`, I have set a limit of 50 concurrent calls of `save()` method. But, I am still facing the same error. I know this question has no code associated with it, but I am looking forward to your suggestions on how to handle this error. Thanks

Comment: Read this section in docs [Connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) (```max_connections``` and  ```superuser_reserved_connections```)and if that does not clear things up then come back with specific concerns.

Comment: Thanks. I am going through this.

Comment: Hey @AdrianKlaver, how can I set max_connections to its maximum?

Comment: There is no set maximum. Each connection is a separate process so it consumes resources, so the number of connections you can have is resource dependent. Generally when you are looking to max the connections the advice is to run them through a pooler so you can recycle them.

Comment: Does calling `save()` method not close the connection itself? Thanks

Comment: I am doing this on a Linux based server 8GB RAM, 160GB storage.

Comment: You have not shown how ```save()``` is being used, so it is hard to say. That fact that you are getting the error would say that the connections are not being closed. Tailing the Postgres log might be useful, depending on what you have the  logging set to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219506/discussion-between-umar-aftab-and-adrian-klaver).